# Can't force a script to try few times when it fails to grab title from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've crated a script to get the title of different shops from some identical webpages. The script is doing fine.

I'm now trying to create a logic within the script to let it try few times if somehow it fails to grab the titles from those pages.

As a test, if I define the line with selector otherwise, as in `name = soup.select_one(".sales-info > h").text`, the script will go for looping indefinitely.

I've tried so far with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = (
    'https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/nizarios-pizza-481135933',
    'https://www.yellowpages.com/nationwide/mip/credo-452182701'
)

def get_title(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    try:
        name = soup.select_one(".sales-info > h1").text
    except Exception:
        print("trying again")
        return get_title(s,link) #I wish to bring about any change here to let the script try few times other than trying indefinitely

    return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
        for link in links:
            print(get_title(s,link))
```

***How can I let the script try few times when it fails to grab title from a webpage?***

PS The webpages that I've used within the script are placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some parameters to specify number of retries, sleep between retries and default value to return if everything fails:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


links = (
    'https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone',
    'https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/static'
)

def get_title(s, link, retries=3, sleep=1, default=''):
    """
        s       -> session
        link    -> url
        retries -> number of retries before return default value
        sleep   -> sleep between tries (in seconds)
        default -> default value to return if every retry fails
    """

    name, current_retry = default, 0
    while current_retry != retries:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        try:
            name = soup.select_one("h8").text
        except Exception:
            print("Retry {}/{}".format(current_retry + 1, retries))
            time.sleep(sleep)
            current_retry += 1

    return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
        for link in links:
            print(get_title(s, link, 3, 1, 'Failed to grab {}'.format(link)))
```

Prints:

```
Retry 1/3
Retry 2/3
Retry 3/3
Failed to grab https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone
Retry 1/3
Retry 2/3
Retry 3/3
Failed to grab https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/static
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to switch from recursion to a loop:

```
def get_title(s,link):
    failed = 0
    while failed < 5:
        try:
            r = s.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
            name = soup.select_one(".sales-info > h1").text
            return name
        except Exception: # Best to specify which one, by the way
            failed += 1
    print('Failed too many times')
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in different ways. Here is another you might wanna consider trying:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    "https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/nizarios-pizza-481135933",
    "https://www.yellowpages.com/nationwide/mip/credo-452182701"
]

def get_title(s,link,counter=0):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    try:
        name = soup.select_one(".sales-info > h").text
    except Exception:
        if counter<=3:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("done trying {} times".format(counter))
            counter += 1
            return get_title(s,link,counter)
        else:
            return None

    return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
        for link in links:
            print(get_title(s,link))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use any retrying library, such as [tenacity](https://github.com/jd/tenacity), [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff). Notice that these libraries usually function as [decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) and your function will simply need to make the import and then call the decorator in a similar fashion to:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tenacity import retry ###or import backoff

...

@retry ###or @backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, requests.exceptions.RequestException)
def get_title(s, link, retries=3, sleep=1, default=''):
...
```